# Spring Kafka client SSL setup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, apache-kafka

My setup:

- JDK 11.0.6
- Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE
- spring-kafka 2.4.1

I have verified my Zookeeper / Kafka / client application in PLAINTEXT, all works fine. I have also verified my keystores / trust stores with the Kafka client tools.

I am using the KafkaAdmin bean to configure my topics, it appears to be failing on the SSL connection:

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, getKafkaHost());
    configs.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
    configs.put("ssl.key.password", "xxx");
    configs.put("ssl.keystore.location", "/keystore/client.keystore.jks");
    configs.put("ssl.keystore.password", "xxx");
    configs.put("ssl.truststore.location", "/keystore/kafka.truststore.jks");
    configs.put("ssl.truststore.password", "xxx");
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}
```

my two JKS files are in src/main/resources/keystore in my Project. `/keystore` doesn't work... it seems like they are getting picked up if I specify `/src/main/resources/keystore/client.keystore.jks`... is that going to work in the real world? At runtime in a standalone tomcat, there is going to be a `/src/main/resources/keystore`?

From my understanding, paths are relative to the `target/classes` folder, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka client or Spring couldn't resolve `.jks` file provided directly with the path even if you provide an absolute path. Provide a relative path like `src/main/resources/keystore` is not a good idea because after the build your `resources` directory content would directly copy into `target/classes` as you know already.

So, bind the file directly to a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` type instance using value annotation from `classpath`.

```
@Value("classpath:certs/keystore/kafka.keystore.jks")
private Resource keystore;

@Value("classpath:certs/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks")
private Resource truststore;
```

Then get the absolute path from that instance like this;

```
configs.put("ssl.keystore.location", keystore.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
configs.put("ssl.truststore.location", truststore.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

As you can see, `Keystore` and `Truststore` file should be in the `classpath`. In my case, they are in `src/resources/certs/keystore` and `src/resources/certs/truststore` directories respectively.