# How to set up ssl file's location in Spring Kafka configuration?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trieng to set up ssl(mTLS) connection between Spring client and Kafka.
I was given two files:

```
  -app.keystore;
  -client.truststore.
```

When I checked the files with `/usr/bin/keytool -list -rfc -keystore app.keystore |grep "Keystore type"` ,
I found out that the type is PKCS12.

I configure Kafka manually, so I have a configuration class with Kafka properties. In configuration I set up properties "ssl.keystore.type" and "ssl.truststore.typ" as "PKCS12".

File locations are set up in application.properties and pasted in configuration using @Value annotation (see code of Configuration down below):

```
kafka.trust-store-location=classpath:ssl/client.truststore
kafka.key-store-location=classpath:ssl/app.keystore
```

Physically files are placed in folder:
maven_module_name/src/main/resources/ssl/client.truststore
maven_module_name/src/main/resources/ssl/app.keystore

When I start the app I have errors:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore classpath:ssl/app.keystore of type PKCS12
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: classpath:ssl/app.keystore
```

This is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {

...

    @Value("${kafka.key-store-location}")
    private String keyStoreLocation;

    @Value("${kafka.truststore-location}")
    private String trustStoreLocation;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        ...
        ...
        props.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
        props.put("ssl.key.password", "password");
        props.put("ssl.keystore.location", keyStoreLocation);
        props.put("ssl.keystore.password", "password");
        props.put("ssl.keystore.type", "PKCS12");
        props.put("ssl.truststore.location", trustStoreLocation);
        props.put("ssl.truststore.password", "password");
        props.put("ssl.truststore.type", "PKCS12");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public <T> ProducerFactory<Long, T> someProducerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public <T> KafkaTemplate<Long, T> someKafkaTemplate() {
        ...
        return template;
    }


}
```

I also tried to use the Resourse interface as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048971/spring-kafka-client-ssl-setup):

```
    @Value("${kafka.key-store-location}")
    private Resource keyStoreLocation;

    @Value("${kafka.trust-store-location}")
    private Resource trustStoreLocation;
```

When I try to get an absolute  path this way:

```
props.put("ssl.keystore.location", keyStoreLocation.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

the app throws an Exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ssl/app.keystore] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ssl/app.keystore
```

Please, suggest to me how to solve the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Comment: @Koman are you facing the same issue? I remember that I fixed this in some way. If you are facing the same issue I'll try to remember back the way I fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7685) in the Kafka client.

It can't load files from the classpath, only the filesystem.  So when you build your app, anything under src/main/resources is packaged in the jar file and not readable from disk directly.

Spring Boot propose a [workaround](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/710) as follows:

```
FileCopyUtils.copy(new ClassPathResource("client.ks").getInputStream(),
            new FileOutputStream("/tmp/client.ks"));
```

Your config file can then look like this:

```
ssl.keystore.location=/tmp/client.ks
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom KeyStoreProvider using security.provider.classes for spring boot kafka client which takes values from credhub or equivalent secret managemnt tool.

Follow these general steps:

- Implement the KeyStoreProvider interface by creating a new class that implements the methods defined in the interface.
- Use a CredHub client library or API to connect to your CredHub instance and retrieve the values for the keys requested by the KeyStoreProvider methods.
- Map the CredHub values to the appropriate KeyStore data types and return them from the KeyStoreProvider methods.
- Configure the Spring Boot Kafka client to use your custom KeyStoreProvider by setting the security.provider.classes property.

Here's some example code that demonstrates how you might implement a custom KeyStoreProvider that retrieves values from CredHub and configure the Spring Boot Kafka client to use it:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException;
import org.springframework.credhub.core.CredHubProperties;
import org.springframework.credhub.core.CredHubTemplate;
import org.springframework.credhub.support.CredentialDetails;
import org.springframework.credhub.support.CredentialName;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.keygen.StringKeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.keygen.KeyGenerators;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.keygen.BytesKeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.keygen.BytesKeyGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CredHubKeyStoreProvider implements KeyStoreProvider {

    private final CredHubTemplate credHubTemplate;
    private final StringKeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerators.string();
    private final Map<String, String> keyNameMapping;

    public CredHubKeyStoreProvider(CredHubProperties credHubProperties, Map<String, String> keyNameMapping) {
        this.credHubTemplate = new CredHubTemplate(credHubProperties);
        this.keyNameMapping = keyNameMapping;
    }

    @Override
    public KeyStore getKeyStore() throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : keyNameMapping.entrySet()) {
            String alias = entry.getKey();
            String credHubName = entry.getValue();
            CredentialDetails<?> credentialDetails = credHubTemplate.getByName(new CredentialName(credHubName));
            if (credentialDetails != null) {
                Object credentialValue = credentialDetails.getValue();
                if (credentialValue instanceof byte[]) {
                    keyStore.setKeyEntry(alias, new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec((byte[]) credentialValue, "AES"), null, null);
                } else if (credentialValue instanceof String) {
                    keyStore.setEntry(alias, new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(((String) credentialValue).getBytes(), "AES")), null);
                }
            }
        }
        return keyStore;
    }

    @Override
    public BytesKeyGenerator getBytesKeyGenerator() {
        return keyGenerator;
    }

    @Override
    public StringKeyGenerator getStringKeyGenerator() {
        return keyGenerator;
    }
}
```

To configure the Spring Boot Kafka client to use your custom KeyStoreProvider, you can set the security.provider.classes property in your application's configuration, as follows:

```
spring.kafka.security.provider.classes=com.example.CredHubKeyStoreProvider
```

In this example, com.example.CredHubKeyStoreProvider is the fully qualified name of your custom KeyStoreProvider implementation.

Unfortunately, `ssl.keystore.location` will need to be set to a readable file, even though it is not used by our KeyStore implementation, so we set it to /dev/null and we set `ssl.keystore.password` to ignored.

Note that you may also need to configure additional properties related to SSL and security in your application's configuration, depending on your Kafka cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mdarwin!
Above answer to copy the JKS file from classpath to the project folder worked for me.
The only difference is that I did not create any directory to store the file in.
Hence my code looks like:

```
FileCopyUtils.copy(new ClassPathResource("truststore.jks").getInputStream(),
                new FileOutputStream("truststore.jks"));
```

And in application yml I added below config.

```
trust-store-location: file:truststore.jks
```

JFYI, I did not create any configuration for the Kafka. It was all done by Spring boot itself.

Also, let me add the imports so that there will be confusion for visitors.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;
```